# How to set working directory for tensorflow

Tags: python, tensorflow

I installed tensorflow in my machine using both **pip** and **conda** installation. I can import it in my **python idle** as well as in `C:\Users\Anaconda3\envs\tensorflow\Scripts` this directory using jupyter notebook. when I want to import in another directory in jupyter notebook, it shows me

> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'tensorflow'.

How can I import it in my working directory?

Comment: In the top right corner of your notebook does it say Python 3 or something like Python 3: tensorflow?

Comment: yes. it shows only python 3.

Comment: Ok I think your jupyter notebook is running in a different conda environment

Comment: how can i fix this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your comments it seems you are running your jupyter-notebook from the wrong conda environment (your base environment rather than the tensorflow one you have created). This is why the packages don't appear to be installed.

Make sure your have `jupyter` installed in your tensorflow environment and also install `nb_conda`. You can do that with:

```
conda install jupyter nb_conda -n tensorflow
```

Then launch jupyter from within your tensorflow environment and you should see it in the list of kernels

Comment: @estiak_emon Glad to hear it, if this helped feel free to mark the answer as correct so others with the same problem can find it

Comment: Done..other problem appears. tensorflow doesn't work in spyder